Magento Modules Decomposition
By looking into Magento Core modules, I can see some of them split into very small parts of same functionality, like this one listed below.
I can't really find on the docs any mention of this approach, and most of the time me and my team would be creating one module that encapsulates the whole functionality.
By doing some research I came across the term Module Decomposition. But I can't really find in-depth information/guides about it.
I like the idea, and it seems to be used to keep the modularity even more modular and simpler.
I would appreciate your insight and if you can point me to some sort of docs about it.
module-login-as-customer
module-login-as-customer-admin-ui
module-login-as-customer-api
module-login-as-customer-assistance
module-login-as-customer-frontend-ui
module-login-as-customer-graph-ql
module-login-as-customer-log
module-login-as-customer-logging
module-login-as-customer-page-cache
module-login-as-customer-quote
module-login-as-customer-sales
module-login-as-customer-website-restriction

